# Creating nested hash - Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash, nested

I have two unique hashes and I want to write a code to create a single nested hash from those two. I understand one can create a nested hash manually, but I'd rather be able to write code to do that.

```
cats = {"name" => "alpha", "weight" => "10 pounds"}
dogs = ("name" => "beta", "weight"=>"20 pounds"}
```

Ideally my nested hash would resemble:

```
pets = {"dogs"=>{"name"=>"beta", "weight"=>"20 pounds"}, "cats"=>{"name"=>"alpha", "weight"=>"10 
pounds"}}
```

I'd really appreciate it if someone could break down the code to do the above for me.
Thank you!!

Comment: Unless you're set on string keys, `cats = { name: "alpha", ... }` is a shorter way of doing this. Then `cats[:name]` for example.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it easily like this.

```
pets = {"dogs"=>dogs, "cats"=>cats}
```

Output:

```
{"dogs"=>{"name"=>"beta", "weight"=>"20 pounds"}, "cats"=>{"name"=>"alpha", "weight"=>"10 pounds"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, you can also get all the local variables automatically and save them into a hash:

```
cats = {"name" => "alpha", "weight" => "10 pounds"}
dogs = {"name" => "beta", "weight"=>"20 pounds"}

puts binding.local_variables.map{|var| [var.to_s, binding.local_variable_get(var)] }.to_h
# {"cats"=>{"name"=>"alpha", "weight"=>"10 pounds"}, "dogs"=>{"name"=>"beta", "weight"=>"20 pounds"}}
```

But please the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64446716/6419007) instead.